# Fragment Transaction Commit: State Loss in OnClick?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I still dont seem to get this State Loss error when commiting a fragment. I have a ListView with this OnClickListener:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
           fragmentTabActivity.addFragments(MainTabHostActivity.getTabNames()[0], new OpenerLocationListFragment(), true);
           break;
    }
}
```

And this is my addFragments Method:

```
    public void addFragments(String tabName, Fragment fragment, boolean add) {
    if (add) {
        hMapTabs.get(tabName).add(fragment);
    }

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

How can it lose his state in this short time frame? I can understand why it happens in Asynctasks but what should i do different here (other than allowing the state loss)? Has anybody suggestions?

Comment: What does the OpenerLocationListFragment() constructor look like? Shouldn't you be passing in OpenerLocationListFragment instead of Fragment?  It may have to do with the cast.

Comment: There is no constructor, so only the default ListFragment one is called. Do you mean in my addFragments method? Then i would have to rewrite it for every Fragment but i can try it.
I forgot to add that it is a rare crash, I never got it on my test devices.

Comment: Then it probably isn't what I suggested.  :(

Comment: have a same behavior